# combinations for large n in python

Tags: python, combinations, dask, python-itertools, dask-delayed

I'm trying to calculate the combinations of the number 62977 in pairs, and then add this as a new column to my dask data frame.
unfortunately I get a memory error even when using delayed function in dask and I don't know how to find a more efficient way. I have to process all of these combinations.

I tried this so far:

```
da.from_delayed(delayed(lambda: np.array(list(combinations(range(file_len), 2)))),shape=(len(list(combinations(range(file_len), 2))), 2), dtype=int, meta=('comb', int))
```

file_len=62977

and i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
MemoryError
```

is there another way?

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). And you can write everything in one line, but it doesn't mean you should.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to produce 1983082753 pairs ? How large is a single pair ?

Comment: The numpy array you're trying to create will use ~31.7GB of memory. You're essentially doing creating it *twice*, once to initialize your array and another time to compute the shape for dask. You can save at least half the memory by specifying the shape as `(file_size * (file_size-1))/2, 2)`.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I want to create a list of combinations pairs starting from 0 to 62977 and add it as a new column to my dask data frame, so starting with (0,1), (0,2), (0,3),.... (62976, 62977)

Comment: @Seon I tried but I get this error: da.from_delayed(delayed(lambda: np.array(list(combinations(range(file_len), 2)))),shape=((62977 * (62977-1))/2, 2), dtype=int, meta=('comb', (int, int)))

Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()